# SwiftUI - Animating HStack onTapGesture

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to animate an HStack onTapGesture just like a Picker works (you tap it, and it changes to gray for a few moments). However, I can't seem to do this.

This is a simplified version of my HStack code for viewing easiness:

```
HStack {
  Image("logo_abc")
     .resizable()
     .renderingMode(.original)
     .frame(width:20, height: 20)
     .padding(.leading, 10)
  HStack {
     Text("Name")
         .fontWeight(.bold)
         .foregroundColor(Color.black)
     Text("Code")
         .font(.subheadline)
         .foregroundColor(Color.black)
  }
  Spacer()
}  
.onTapGesture() {
  //perform action
}
.padding(.top, 10)
```

I've tried wrapping this HStack with a button, but the button animation is not what I'm looking for.

It might be worth mentioning that this HStack is inside a RefreshableScrollView.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, can anyone give me an idea on how to approach it?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

This is the effect I'm looking for. That gray color change onTap.

[image]

Comment: Would you demo somehow which effect do you want?

Comment: Hi @Asperi. I just updated my question with the demo. Sorry for not doing it earlier.

Comment: It is standard Form/List highlight for row having active control. List highlights row with button in the same way.

Comment: I've tried wrapping this HStack in a List and it doesn't work. Please note this is inside a RefreshableScrollView